# servicestate of the android phone

Tags: android, networking

In one of my app i wanted to check the service state of the android phone
before sending sms. I have used the following code to do that

```
                //check service
    ServiceState pstate = new ServiceState();
    if(pstate.getState() != ServiceState.STATE_IN_SERVICE)
        {
        Log.v(TAG,"service state" +pstate.getState());
        Toast.makeText(Myactivity.this, "error string", 2000).show();
        return;
        }
```

But the code always returns with OUT_OF_SERVICE ( value of 1 in +pstate.getState)

Please let me know what is the reliable way to check whether the phone is in STATE_IN_SERVICE or not?

This code was checked in FROYO version.

Answer (score 0):

Not a satisfactory answer really, but I've had he same problem and kept wasting time, but it would just not work on my FROYO version aswell.

But using the [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) and [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) this worked perfectly fine. For your case I'd suggest using a wrapper instead of instantiating the ServiceState directly, ie

```
    //declare current state
    ServiceState myServiceState = new ServiceState();
    PhoneStateListener listener = null; // not sure if this is needed really..


    // nifty getter
    public ServiceState getServiceState(){ return myServiceState; }


    //setup listener (eg. in onCreate)
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState){
            myServiceState = serviceState;
        }
    };
    tm.listen(listener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);


    // to be called when destroying your context
    public void unregisterListener(){
        // something like..
        tm.listen(listener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }


    //check service
    ServiceState pstate = getServiceState();
    if(pstate.getState() != ServiceState.STATE_IN_SERVICE)
    {
        Log.v(TAG,"service state" +pstate.getState());
        Toast.makeText(Myactivity.this, "error string", 2000).show();
        return;
    }
```

A lazier solution would be moving the listener-setup into the getter and registering it only when actually called, if ever, and only saving if the service is available. ie

```
    //declaration
    boolean isAvailable = false;
    PhoneStateListener listener = null;


    // more nifty getter
    public boolean isServiceAvailable(){
        if (listener == null){
            //setup listener if not yet done
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onServiceStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState){
                    isAvailable = serviceState.getState() == ServiceState.STATE_IN_SERVICE;
                }
            };
            tm.listen(listener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);
        }
        return isAvailable;
    }

    // to be called when destroying your context
    public void unregisterListener(){
        // something like..
        if (lister != null){
            tm.listen(listener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        }
    }



    //check service
    if(! isServiceAvailable())
    {
        Log.v(TAG,"service state" +pstate.getState());
        Toast.makeText(Myactivity.this, "error string", 2000).show();
        return;
    }
```

But be aware, that would require the listener to get called immediately upon registration, otherwise you'll end up with arbitrary results - so make sure to check that.